# Odoo server does not start in Windows 10

Tags: windows, server, odoo

I download and install odoo 13 on its official community version page, then when I install everything fine and I start odoo, the browser opens with the localhost 8069 that is the odoo port and it doesn't open anything, the server just doesn't Starts

[image]

I running odoo-bin in this is my error logs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to start Odoo manually (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo-bin"`) then check for errors in the log

Comment: How i can do it? Sorry, i really new in odoo and y did not find a good solved on this problem

Comment: Locate the Odoo folder and try to start it from terminal like in the command above.

Comment: Yes, I am C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Odoo 13.0 \ python \ python.exe running that program, which is python and now what do I put in that terminal? I will modify the question with a photo

Comment: You need to run odoo-bin using that executable of python, try to run the command I provided in the first comment and update the question with the error log

Comment: The PyPDF2 module should be in /Lib/site-packages. Try to start odoo-bin.py script using the python version inside Odoo 13.0 directory

Comment: Yeah, the folder PyPDF2 always been in lib/site-packages, i try run odoo-bin in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0. This directory is the root of odoo, and not run. Do I need to configure something else on my computer also after installing odoo 13 community?

Comment: In the screenshot you run the odoo script using the python command which is probably different from the one provided by the odoo installer. Copy the command from my first comment.

Comment: Did you get the log error message?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am already running it using the python that Odoo brings and not an external one, I will attach the image

Comment: You need to [configure PostgreSQL](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html#postgresql).

Comment: Yeah it is, Thank you. Leave your answer and I will score you

Comment: You are welcome, added an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odoo could not connect to PostgreSQL, so you need to create a new user. You can check the [PostgreSQL](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html#postgresql) configuration when starting Odoo from source on Windows (Listed below).

**PostgreSQL**

Odoo uses PostgreSQL as database management system. Download and install PostgreSQL
(supported version: 10.0 and later).

By default, the only user is `postgres` but Odoo forbids connecting as `postgres`, so you need to
create a new PostgreSQL user:

1. Add PostgreSQL’s `bin` directory (by default: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL&lt;version>\bin`) to
   your `PATH`.
2. Create a postgres user with a password using the pg admin gui:

   1. Open **pgAdmin**.
   2. Double-click the server to create a connection.
   3. Select Object ‣ Create ‣ Login/Group Role.
   4. Enter the username in the **Role Name** field (e.g. `odoo`).
   5. Open the **Definition** tab and enter the password (e.g. `odoo`), then click **Save**.
   6. Open the **Privileges** tab and switch **Can login?** to `Yes` and **Create database?** to
      `Yes`.